# Safe to put Openwrt in DMZ?

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, openwrt

I currently have my openwrt router setup 'behind' my fios actiontec router. I am trying to get OpenVPN and having issues. I'm wondering if putting the openwrt router in the DMZ on the fios router would be a good idea? I seem some references to 'double NATing' which I think I now doing. If I put the openwrt router in the DMZ is there any configuration I need to change to make sure it's not 'double NATing'. Basically I'd like to just treat the fios actiontec router as a modem in this case and send all traffic to the openwrt router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it into DMZ, it will forward everything to the other router by design. If you are able to turn off DHCP on one of them then let the other handle doling out addresses, then you should be free of any mess. The WRT should handle the firewalling properly. You should be covered.

Comment: Sorry, quick question, why the need to turn off DHCP on one of them? Currently I've disabled wifi etc on the verizon router and connected the openwrt router to it. That is the only thing giving out leases on my network.